# Visual Studio - JS file versioning

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, caching

I'm working on a thin client web project - front end part only - with visual studio. I need to have the js and css file versioning within the htmls to remove the browser caching issue. Is there any way that I can achieve this with VS? ( I'm using SVN for the code repo )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you are trying to burst the cache or invalidate the cache by trying to have new version of file every time the client requests the page from server. You can either append a query string to the URL of the CSS/javscript file links embedded in your HTML like :

`<script src="//xyz.com/abc.js?12345"></script>`

You can generate the query string dynamically using current date time or using some random number generation and add it as query string to the URL.

Or if you wish to maintain the files with different version numbers in the source code, something like abc.v1.js and abc.v2.js, you can use gulp or grunt task to generate the file and update the html with the version link

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. You can add a ?v=3.4.5.2 like versioning to the file and then replace the matching regex with the update revision num + timestamp by a before build script